# Does not saves log to the file when i run the script using systemd

Tags: php, systemd

I am running a php script under systemd service, but I am testing this script at the moment and am saving to log using

```
 $log  = "Api: " .$de->detail. " | ".date("h:i:sa"). " UTC".PHP_EOL;
         file_put_contents('./log_'.date("j.n.Y").'.txt', $log, FILE_APPEND);
```

This runs script and saves to a file if i run the script manually , but if i run the script using systemd it won't save anything to that log file?

Comment: Try adding a change dir on the top of your script

chdir(dirname(__FILE__));

Comment: @Shahaf is correct. Also, check permissions for systemd to the dir / file.